# flutter Webview didnt works on IOS device but in emulator all good

Tags: ios, flutter

Hello guys in ios device i got white screen webview
in  IOS emulator all works good please help me

```
      WebView(
      initialUrl: "google.com",
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS
In order for Webview to work correctly, you need to add a new key to `ios/Runner/Info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` is for iOS 10+ and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` for iOS 9.

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
need to add it upper dict or in dict?

Comment: use  upper dict to add the key

Comment: i must create one more dict ? under main dict?

Comment: No, in your dict

 ```    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>```

Paste this lines

Comment: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7443EFFA-F6F2-435E-B2FE-1D76D94A110A/Runner.app/Frameworks/webview_flutter.framework/webview_flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
\

Comment: I got this problem

Answer (score 1):

Opt-in to the embedded views preview by adding a boolean property to the app's Info.plist file with the key io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and the value YES.

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<string>YES</string>
```

Simply add the line on ios/Runner/info.plist